# Why is supportFragmentManager.popBackStack() not working correctly?

Tags: android

I've got an Activity that extends AppCompatActivity. That activity manages a toolbar and contains 2 fragments; Fragment1 and Fragment2.

To show a fragment I use this code:

```
    private fun showFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, tag)
            addToBackStack(null)
        }.commit()
    }
```

And I have 2 helper methods to display those 2 fragments:

```
    override fun showFragment1() {
        showFragment(MyFragment1(), MyFragment1.TAG)
    }

    override fun showFragment2() {
        showFragment(MyFragment2(), MyFragment2.TAG)
    }
```

So when I start my activity, my app seems to work correctly.  I showFragment1(), press a button and showFragment2(). And this is where things start to go wrong.  When in Fragment2 if the user presses the back button my Activity closes/finishes. As far as I know I'm correctly adding these fragments to the backstack so pressing the back button while in Fragment2 SHOULD take me to Fragment1 right?  In an attempt to troubleshoot this I overwrote onBackPressed() with this:

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

Which did not help. When paused in the debugger I can see that the backStackEntryCount is 2 and supportFragmentManager.popBackStack() is firing and still closing my activity. So what am I doing wrong? My assumption is that even though the backStack entry count shows a count of 2 I'm somehow adding these entries incorrectly. I can see the backstack contains entries for both Fragment1 and Fragment2. What can I do so that this works as I intend...so that pressing the back button while on Fragment2 pops Fragment2 off the backstack and returns me to the previous backstack item (Fragment1)?

BTW, I've also attempted this code:

```
    supportFragmentManager.commit {
        setReorderingAllowed(true)
        replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment,tag)
        addToBackStack(tag)
    }
```

Which also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your second fragments action and it should work.

```
<action
android:id="@+id/action_dataFragment_to_homeFragment
app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
app:popUp To Inclusivle="true" />
```